# How to create MongoDB Long DataType from String in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Reading the page about the MongoDB [Long Datatype](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/long.html) - it says I create one like this:

```
var myLong = new Long(low, high);
```

Where low and high are signed 32 bit parts of the larger 64 bit number...

I have got the following number as a string using [node-bigint](https://github.com/substack/node-bigint)

```
'164150943396226415094339622641509433'
```

How do I convert this 64-bit!?! string into the 32-bit low and high bits needed for the Long constructor...

Also - would an indexed Mongo $gt search be quicker with a string or the Long?

Thanks in advance - I'm out of my depth...

**EDIT 1**

Right - on the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973275/node-js-saving-large-floating-point-numbers-into-mongo-for-searching) (much fuzzier) thread - the answer is that this number is too big for 64 bit....

So - my question is, what is the fastest way to save and search this number in 2 parts, so the original string becomes:

```
'164150943396226415' and '094339622641509433'
```

Should I turn them into Longs (in which case what about the leading zero) or is string searching as fast / slower...

You could re-phrase the question:

In MongoDB would a Long or String be faster for:

```
'164150943396226415'
```

Thanks again....

Comment: No sure if you saw my update in your original thread, but that number is way too big to store in 64 bits.  The largest value possible is 2^63-1 or 9223372036854775807.

Comment: try it out to see what is faster ;)

Comment: @BInoCarlos Another sanity check: I think you headed down this path because you thought that JavaScript and MongoDB only support 32-bit floats.  That's not correct; they both support double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point.  Are you sure that's not enough for your purposes?

Comment: matz3 - I'm stuck trying to get my long string as as real Long before I can test for speed...

@JohnnyHK - but when I do 87/53 in Javascript I get a truncated number - so I used bigint which gives me a string - I don't know enough to convert this string into the 2-composite 32-bit parts that the Long constructor requires...

Comment: @BInoCarlos 87/53 is always going to be truncated somewhere.  Windows calc.exe and the `bigint` node libaray are providing arbitrary precision, that's why they're longer than the 64-bit float of native JavaScript.  So it's really a question of what precision do you actually require?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I need the precision of:

    '164150943396226415094339622641509433'

I.e. I need to be able to search for numbers that are greater or less than the number above...

Evidently this is hard : ) So I'm stuck on just comparing strings - the remaining question is:

How could I turn the string above into a Long and if the answer is "you can't" - is there any other way I can search for numbers gt/lt the one above inside of Mongo (other than strings)?

Answer (score 0):

Right!

I've been talking to my friend - he has explained all of my mis-guided assumptions...

The number '164150943396226415094339622641509433' is too big for 64-bit...

He said searching strings will always go char by char and that splitting the number into a 2 compliment pair of actual 64 bit numbers is quicker...

So, for the number above we have:

```
var higher = Long.fromString('1641509433962264150');
var lower = Long.fromString('94339622641509433');
```

And then do a:

```
( this.higher > that.higher ) && (this.lower > that.lower)
```

Sorry for asking a question that was based on my own mis-understanding : )